# Adding share action/extension in React Native

Tags: react-native

Trying to build a React Native app that injects a menu item in the Share menu (Share Action for Android, Share Extension for iOS) and receives shared items in the app. Is there a component for this, and if not what's the best way to build one?

Comment: have you found the solution? I believe the answer below is not what you've been asking about

Comment: Also interested to know. Clearly, the answer below doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I implemented a module for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-menu (currently just works for Android).

That's how to use it:

Install the module:

`npm i --save react-native-share-menu`

In android/settings.gradle:

```
...
include ':react-native-share-menu', ':app'
project(':react-native-share-menu').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-share-menu/android')
```

In android/app/build.gradle:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':react-native-share-menu')
}
```

Register module (in MainActivity.java):

```
import com.meedan.ShareMenuPackage;  // <--- import 

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
......
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new ShareMenuPackage()  // <------ add here      
        );
    }
......
}
```

Example:

```
import React, {
    AppRegistry,
    Component,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import ShareMenu from 'react-native-share-menu';

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            sharedText: null
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        var that = this;
        ShareMenu.getSharedText((text :string) => {
            if (text && text.length) {
                that.setState({ sharedText: text });
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        var text = this.state.sharedText;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Shared text: {text}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Test', () => Test);
```

Comment: Update: this component now supports iOS too.

Comment: hi @Caio when you want to publish, what do you do? do you use the bundle from main project on extension? or do you copy paste that bundle on the extension? thanks!

Comment: @MaKo I just generate a bundle of the main project, which will include the extension

Comment: Hi @CaioAlmeida, interestingly, the action extension does not show up on my device while in the simulator it works fine (same device version and iOS version). Any ideas?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately I'm looking for an iOS developer to maintain the iOS version :(
https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu/issues/22#issuecomment-351215786

Answer (score -4):

You can use the built in component: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html#content

Or you can use this component which can accept any view you want and makes it look like the iOS share component:

https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-custom-action-sheet

These are designed for iOS. For Android (and also iOS), you can use this:
https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share

Answer (score -6):

You can use the new Share api introduced in 0.33. I actually have a video on how to do this here: http://codecookbook.co/post/how-to-share-text-from-your-react-native-app/

Comment: If you mean this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/sharing then you're referring to the inverse operation: opening a share menu from within the RN app to an external site or other app. The question here is to inject a share ITEM that shows up in all apps to send content to the RN app.