# Adding share action in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Trying to build a React Native app that **injects a menu item in the Share menu** (Share Action for Android, Share Extension for iOS). Is there a component for this, and if not what's the best way to build one?

I don't need to create ActionSheet in my app, i need to **injects a menu item in the Share menu** to allow users share urls from browser to my app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980233/8148005 , where this question is obviously copied from.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add some native code to your project. I don't have experience doing this for iOS, but here's an outline for how to do it on Android.

Simplifying the [Android documentation's example](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html), you should be able to write something like this to allow other apps to share a text string "into" your app:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<activity android:name="<your_app>.MainActivity">
    <!-- Allow users to launch your app directly -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- Allow other apps to "share" with your app -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
...
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    // Match the intent specified in AndroidManifest.xml
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && "text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
    } 
}
...
```

If you write most of your application logic in Javascript using React Native, you'll probably want `handleSendText` to trigger a Javascript event — see the [React Native docs on native modules](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript) for information about how to do this.